# Regexp, find in a procedure last "end" to replace with another word

Tags: python, regex, oracle

I have tried to replace in all procedures some mistakes. Now, I need to find last "end;" in procedure and replace it with another text.
I wrote like: `(\s.*)(end|END)(.*(;).*)`
But in work not correctly, it also replace some words in the middle of the text. I using re biblio from python.

Comment: Last `end` can be replaced with `re.sub(r'(?si)(.*)\bend\b', r'\g<1>some other word', text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
result = re.sub(r'(?si)(.*)\bend\b', r'\g<1>some other word', text)
```

The regex matches

- `(?si)` - an inline `re.DOTALL` (`s`) and `re.IGNORECASE` (`i`) modifier
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `\bend\b` -a whole word `end`.

The `\g<1>some other word` replacement is the Group 1 value (I used `\g<1>` since it will be helpful if your `some other word` starts with a digit) plus your word.

**NOTE**: if your `some other word` can contain literal backslashes, do not forget to double them.

Comment: How i can modify this if i also need to take ; ?
So, i have to replace 'end;' or 'end ;'

Comment: @TimurKutuev You can replace `\bend\b` with `\bend\b(?:\s*;)?`